# Перебрать файл с URL и получить HTTP-код для каждого URL

Tags: linux, bash, curl, sed, awk

У меня есть текстовый файл `url.txt` содержащий `URL` на новой строке и ничего больше.

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com
https://meta.stackoverflow.com
```

Мне нужно получить `HTTP`-код каждого `URL`.

```
curl -ILks https://ru.stackoverflow.com | awk '/^HTTP/{print $2}'
curl -ILks https://stackoverflow.com | awk '/^HTTP/{print $2}'
curl -ILks https://meta.stackoverflow.com | awk '/^HTTP/{print $2}'
```

И получить на выходе такой ответ

```
200 https://ru.stackoverflow.com
200 https://stackoverflow.com 
200 https://meta.stackoverflow.com
```

Помогите написать изящный скрипт, который получает на вход файл `url.txt` и в `stdout` выводит нужный ответ.

Как в `bash` перебирать построчно текстовый файл испльзуя из него строку в кач-ве аргумента и можно ли это сделать с помощью `awk` и/или `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{system("curl -o /dev/null -ILksw \"%{http_code} \" "$0";echo "$0)}' url.txt
```

п.с

если порядок вывода проверки URL не имеет значения то можно еще добавить ключ `-Z, --parallel` что ускорит получения значений:

```
awk '{system("curl -o /dev/null -IZLksw \"%{http_code} \" "$0";echo "$0)}' url.txt
```

а для еще большего ускорения можно передавать адреса через `xargs` а для `awk` оставить тока окончательную фильтрацию:

```
xargs <url.txt curl -IZLksw '+ %{http_code} %{url_effective}\n' |awk '$1=="+"{print $2,$3}'
```

последний вариант по сравнению с первым у меня отрабатывает в два раза быстрее. ( можно примерно оценить с помощью утилиты `time (...)` )

Comment: Благодарю! Именно то, что я хотел! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Получить нужный формат вывода можно и без обработчиков текста вроде `awk` или `sed`, curl подразумевает формировать ответ программы:

```
-w '%{http_code} %{url_effective}'
```

для того что бы сделать скрипт считывающий из файла url и возвращал данные в stdout достаточно сделать цикл:

```
while read url; do
    curl -o /dev/null -s -w '%{http_code} %{url_effective}\n' "$url"
done < url.txt
```

`http_code` - возвращает код ответа HTTP
`url` - используемый при передаче URL, появился в версии curl 7.75.0
`url_effective` - возвращает последний полученный url, следует учитывать при использовании опции `-L`

Если версия `curl` ниже 7.75.0 и нужны адреса из url.txt, то цикл можно сделать следующим образом:

```
while read url; do
    curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code} $url\n" "$url"
done < url.txt
```

Где мы просто подставляем переменную считанную из файла построчно

Comment: Благодарю!
Уточните, пожалуйста, первую строку кода `while read url; do` как мне инициализировать переменную `url`?
В место неё можно путь к файлу подставить или `$1` если я его передаю параметром?

Comment: @ИльяИндиго `url` в примерах приведенных мной считывается из файла `url.txt` который передает содержимое для построчного считывания тут `done < url.txt` и вы так же можете поставить вместо него `$1` что бы вызывать скрипт с параметром.

Comment: Благодарю! Не в первый раз уже, путаюсь в `bash`-конструкциях.